# Why do I see a difference between validation AUC's calculated in the keras model.fit function vs sklearn.metrics.auc() function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm noticing a difference in AUC's between the validation AUC calculated in the model.fit() function vs sklearn.metrics.auc() function.

In my workflow, I train a Keras model with a callback that records the validation AUC after each epoch and, at the end of training, saves the model with the best validation AUC. The filename of this saved model corresponds to the value of the best validation AUC, which in my case was 0.745 (Code Block 1).

However, when I use the same validation dataset and labels, along with the best model saved by Keras, and manually calculate the validation AUC using the sklearn library (Code Block 2), I obtain a lower AUC value than the one saved by Keras.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

CODE BLOCK 1 (0.745 AUC of best model named 'epoch_7_best-val-auc_0.745.hdf5')

```
from sklearn import metrics

class EpochCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, save_path):
        super(EpochCallback, self).__init__()
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.best_model = None
        self.best_val_auc = 0
        self.best_val_epoch = 0
                
    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        filepath = os.path.join(self.save_path, "epoch_"+str(self.best_val_epoch)+"_best-val-auc_" + str('%.3f'% self.best_val_auc) + '.hdf5')
        self.best_model.save(filepath)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        
        if logs.get('val_auc') > self.best_val_auc:
            self.best_model = self.model
            self.best_val_auc = logs.get('val_auc')
            self.best_val_epoch = epoch

ecallback = EpochCallback(sv_dir_base)

reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
                'val_loss',
                factor=factor,
                patience=patience,
                min_lr=1e-4 * 0.001)

history = model.fit(training_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=50, callbacks=[ecallback, reduce_lr])
```

CODE BLOCK 2 (0.718 AUC)

```
model = keras.models.load_model('epoch_7_best-val-auc_0.745.hdf5')
val_predicted = model(val_dataset)
fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Comment: TF computes AUC per batch then takes the average between them